# Not able to display images from static folder using Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

[image: My OUTPUT]**This is my home.html**
I'm not able to display the images in static/images/ folder.
Although *[09/Mar/2020 15:52:09] "GET /static/images/mona.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1669
* is displayed in terminal.[image: I have provided a screenshot of the directory so that in case any files are not misplaced by me, or in the wrong folder]

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    {% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static '/css/style.css' %} />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    {% include "includes/header.html" %}

    <div class="pt-5">
        <div class="card d-inline-block">
            <img src={% static 'images/mona.jpeg' %} alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>Mona Lisa</b></h4>
                <p><a href="#">Architect & Engineer</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card d-inline-block">
            <img src={% static "images/mona.jpg" %} alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>The Scream</b></h4>
                <p><a href="#">Architect & Engineer</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% include "includes/footer.html" %}
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Comment: Can you share the url of image which is creating from inspect element?

Comment: it is in the static folder, ../static/images/mona.jpg

Comment: use 'mona.jpg' as mona.jpeg does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

add quotes around source as follows

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'images/mona.jpeg' %}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

In production static files are served by the web server (apache, nginx)

in development the files in app_name/static/app_name will be served automatically if you are using  django.contrib.staticfiles and DEBUG is set to True.

If the files are uploaded by the user in your web app you need to edit your base urls.py file as below

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

For more info on this see  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
```

Comment: I already have made the above necessary changes, but still facing the issue

Comment: can you post your settings.py file and directory structure?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys, it was a typo error. So dumb of me....

In settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'the7thstreet/static'),
 '/var/www/static',
 ]
```

Corrected

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
 '/var/www/static',
 ]
```

[image]